# Fuse WithinPixels Library Versions

Tags: angularjs, html, material-design, angular-material

Fuse http://fuse-angular-material.withinpixels.com/dashboard-project
this is the library which I want to use in my project. But, before buying it i want to know the library version on which it is based upon. I wanted to know which version on angular.material library it is using so that it doesn't conflicts with the one that I'm using in my current project. I'm using v0.11.4 of Angular Material https://material.angularjs.org/. Can somebody tell me which version are they using.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't easier ask them this? How can we know it?

Comment: By the way if you look at source code you can find they use AngularJS v1.4.7

Comment: One cannot ask them without buying it. I wanted to know the version of angular material that they were using. Anyways I have already purchased it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply guys.

Comment: http://withinpixels.com/themes/fuse/changelog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source http://withinpixels.com/themes/fuse/changelog

Version 1.4.0 (2016-05-25) - Updated to Angular 1.5.5 and Angular Material 1.0.9

Version 1.3.0 (2016-02-25) - Updated to Angular 1.5.0 and Angular Material 1.0.5